# Transitive models and CH

Tags: set-theory, forcing

The following was asked on stackexchange but I think it also belongs here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513446/transitive-models-and-ch

Suppose $M, N$ are two countable transitive models of ZFC which have same ordinals, cofinalities and reals (but not necessarily same sets of reals!). Suppose $M$ models the continuum hypothesis. Can we conclude that $N$ also models continuum hypothesis? I can see that if this fails, then neither one of $M, N$ is included in the other. But what if $M, N$ are incomparable.

Comment: CW by request of Ashutosh, because he was only relaying the question.

Comment: I should clarify that Monroe had an entire machinery (anonymous collapse and he spoke about it in GSCL 2014) to get much stronger results around April 2014.

Comment: I actually answered the question on Math.SE.

Comment: (There are other ways to relay questions from MSE to MO, by the way. For example: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1967/interesting-and-not-sufficiently-answered-questions-on-math-se)

Comment: @Asaf, if I am not mistaken, the question was answered here before your answer there, although the link to Monroe's paper over on MSE by hot_queen came even earlier.

Comment: @Joel: Yes, that is correct. I haven't seen this thread until after I had posted my answer, though. Which is why I generally *despise* cross-posting. I wouldn't have bothered to answer if I had seen your answer here. Which is why I'm annoyed that nobody thought that perhaps a link on the original question on MSE is a good idea.

Comment: To my way of thinking, the question would have been well-placed on MO from the start.

Comment: @Joel: That may or may not be true, but it is irrelevant to the duplication of effort on my side.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you answered over there, since we now have essentially three arguments: Monroe's, mine and yours. They are, however, all using essentially the same idea, namely, that of rearranging the Cohen reals on different cardinals inside the model, which are the same in the place where the construction is undertaken.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This strange situation can indeed happen.

Start with a countable transitive model of set theory $W$,
satisfying CH, and let $G$ be $W$-generic for the forcing
$\newcommand\Add{\text{Add}}\Add(\omega,\omega_1)^W$. So the model
$M=W[G]$ continues to satisfy CH. Now, let $g$ be $W[G]$-generic
for the collapse of $\omega_2^W$ to $\omega_1^W$, using the
collapse forcing as it is defined in $W$, and temporarily consider
$W[G][g]$. Notice that the collapse forcing was countably closed
in $W$, and so it remains at least countably distributive in
$W[G]$. So we have added no new countable sequences of ordinals in
going from $W[G]$ to $W[G][g]$. Inside $W[G][g]$, the ordinals
$\omega_1^W$ and $\omega_2^W$ are now in bijection, and so there
is an isomorphism $\pi:\Add(\omega,\omega_1)^W\cong
\Add(\omega,\omega_2)^W$ between these two forcing notions as posets. Furthermore, since by design
the bijection of the ordinals has the property that every
countable piece of it is in $W$, the same property is true for
this isomorphism $\pi$. Let
$H=\pi[G]\subset\Add(\omega,\omega_2)^W$ be the isomorphic copy of
$G$ induced by the isomorphism $\pi$. I claim that $H$ is
$W$-generic for $\Add(\omega,\omega_2)^W$, because if $A$ is any
maximal antichain in this forcing in $W$, then by the c.c.c. it
follows that $A$ is countable, and so
$\pi^{-1}A\subset\Add(\omega,\omega_1)^W$ is a maximal antichain
in $W$ for the first forcing, since this much of $\pi$ is in $W$.
And so, since $G$ must meet $\pi^{-1}A$, it follows that $H$ meets
$A$; so $H$ is $W$-generic, and we may let $N=W[H]$. So $N$ is a
model of $\neg\text{CH}$, since we've added $\omega_2$ many Cohen
reals. Both $M$ and $N$ are c.c.c. extensions of $W$, and so they
have the same cardinals and cofinalities.

Let's now argue that they have the same reals. First off, every
real of $N=W[H]$ is certainly in $W[G][g]$, where $H$ is
constructed, and the reals of $W[G][g]$ are the same as the reals
of $W[G]=M$, since the $g$ forcing is countably distributive. So
every reals of $N$ is in $M$. Conversely, if $x$ is a real in
$M=W[G]$, then $x$ is in $W[G\upharpoonright\alpha]$ for some
$\alpha<\omega_1$. And since
$\pi\upharpoonright\Add(\omega,\alpha)$ is in $W$, it follows that
$x$ is in $W[H\upharpoonright\pi[\alpha]]$, which is contained in
$W[H]=N$. So they have the same reals.

In conclusion, $M$ and $N$ have the same reals, the same
cardinals, the same cofinalities, but one has CH and one does not,
as desired.

One may cast the argument in terms of forcing over $V$; there is no need to go to countable transitive models. Namely, start in $V$, with CH, and then force to add $\omega_1$ many Cohen reals to form $V[G]$. Now collapse $\omega_2$ to $\omega_1$ using the ground model collapse, and in $V[G][g]$ define $H$ as the copy of $G$ induced by that isomorphism. It now follows by the argument above that $V[G]$ and $V[H]$ have the same reals, the same cardinals and cofinalities, but one has CH and the other does not.

And of course, there is nothing special about $\omega_2$ in these arguments, we could have used $\omega_3$ or any other regular cardinal in $W$ just as easily.

Comment: The situation is possible. See my answer on math.SE

Comment: But haven't I also given a proof here that it happens? I find my argument to be more direct, since it doesn't use symmetric models. There is no need to consider $L(\mathbb{R})$ explicitly, although of course the models will have the same $L(\mathbb{R})$ since they have the same reals.

Comment: Well, sure. Your argument, however, can be reduced to passing through $L(\Bbb R)$, which can be clearer and easier to see why these things work nicely (after forcing over $L(\Bbb R)$ to have say, $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$, you didn't add any new reals, so every real is in $L$ or Cohen over $L$, so this is again a Cohen extension).

Comment: I suppose one can view that as a reduction, but I'm inclined to say that the symmetric model argument can be reduced to a direct forcing argument.